# Jquery custom string comparison function with output percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am looking to write a function in Jquery that compares two strings and returns a percentage of similarity..exactly like the PHP function similar_text:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Ideas on how to tackle this with Jquery/Javascript?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP.JS have it: http://phpjs.org/functions/similar_text:902

Comment: Wow. It's a great resource :)

Comment: Yes!! But be aware it mimics PHP but still working with Javascript, that is concepts of `undefined` and `null` are different.

Comment: hmm looks good but for some reason it isn't running properly.  Shouldn't....`var similar = similar_text("hello", "heljo"); alert(similar);` give me 4 in the alert?

Comment: absolutely nothing, except disable some other features that the script accomplishes, so I"m guessing there is an error in the code?  Does it matter that I'm using Jquery?

Comment: @thepristinedesign: Using jQuery shouldn't make a difference here. I tried running the javascript on my test machine, and it seems to work properly. Make sure that you're calling the function after it is defined.

Comment: I certainly see why it should work.  I can't seem to figure out why the errors occur though..this is frustrating.  This is exactly what I have:   http://pastebin.com/hha0mCvd

Comment: so start firebuging: http://getfirebug.com/ and validate JS: http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: Firebug errors: 573Uncaught TypeError: Object[object DOMWindow] has no method 'similar_text'.  It's recursively calling itself in the function right?  Why does this throw an error though?

Comment: yes it works recursively, maybe you simply defines the function in the wrong place, try to write the html/js from scratch.

Comment: Found it! the recursive calls to this.similar_text did not work I had to get rid of the this. and it worked nicely.  Thank you all for your help