# Want to find out percentage of similarity between two strings jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to find out the similarity between two string in percentage in Jquery. For example

```
string1="Answers to the queries (typically have a lot of queries)"
```

and

```
string2="Answers to the queries (typically have a lot of query)".
```

I want to find out percentage similarity between string1 and string2

Comment: You will have to define "percentage similarity".  What do you expect that to mean?  Percent common words?  Does order of words matter?  Do phrases matter?  Do you need suffix or tense smarts so words are considered similar when they only different in a suffix or tense?  FYI, if you do some searching, there is existing technology/libraries for this kind of stuff.  It's been the subject of many research projects.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780409/jquery-custom-string-comparison-function-with-output-percentage. this is just an example

Answer (score 0):

Does the [phpJs similar_text](http://phpjs.org/functions/similar_text/) function does what you want?